# Arrange tableViewCell by creating Date

Tags: core-data, uitableview

I have app where i use CoreData to fill my tableViewCell's. In that CoreData i have one entity with 4 strings attributes and one Date attribute. 
Is possible to arrange my table cells by this Date attribute?

I have trying search some manual here and on youtube, but unsuccessful.

Comment: take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html, it's exactly what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a sort descriptor to your fetch. e.g.

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"<name_of_date_property" ascending:YES]];
```

Comment: And is possible to implement two buttons to my tableView wich will switch this descriptor? For example between Date attribute and one of my String attribute? Maybe via (if) statements?